# How to do ruqya if you don't know how to read quran?

Tags: quran, ruqya

A long time ago, when I was a teenager I wore a taweez thinking it was going to protect me and so on. However now looking back on it I know that this is was a HUGE mistake and major shirk. I now would like to do ruqya on myself just in case there might be jinn in me even after all these years, but the issue is I don't know how to read quran: surah al baqara. I know surah el fatiha and ayatul kursi etc, but I don't know baqara since it is very long to recite and I don't know arabic. What should i do?

Comment: A raqi told me that, if you cannot read it, then listen to it instead. Also what is this Jinn doing to you? How do you know you are possessed? what are the signs and symptoms you are experiencing?

Comment: Well i dont know for sure. I dont think i may be possessed but i REALLY struggle with procrastination with everything, especially prayer and studying . Can i do ruqya on myself even if im not possessed? Like just in case?

Comment: Did you have these problems before,

Answer (score 1):

you can listen it. 
prepare before listen :

1. wudhu
2. sholat sunnah 2 rakaat
3. make dua, hope allah to help you.
4. Istighfar.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn to recite it without learning the whole language. You can ask someone else to do Ruqya on you as there is a precedent for it in several ahadith, see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52163/).